# How to detect the exact moment when the app is killed?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, onpause, ondestroy

I need to make an api call when the app is being killed but lifecycle callbacks are not called when the user just swipes up the app from recent tasks.

I tried to check onPause, onStop, onDestroyed callbacks but none of them called when I killed the app by swiping it.

Do we have a way to detect the exact moment when the app is killed?

Comment: Once your process is terminated, you cannot make an API call. You are not notified of when your process is about to be terminated, and your process can be terminated at any time when the app's UI is in the background.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, that's what I expected too. I also wonder, would it be possible to start a service and keep checking whether the application process is terminated or not?

Comment: A background service can only run for up to a minute (dropping to several seconds in Android 14, it looks like). Also, by default, a service runs in the same process as does the rest of the application. If you have a foreground service for some other reason, you can use `onTaskRemoved()` to perhaps find out that the user terminated your task ("killed the app by swiping it"), but that is not guaranteed.